# how to create loginpage using struts2 tiles

Tags: java, struts2, tiles, vs-web-application-project, struts2-tiles-plugin

I created web application in struts2 concept and that application is call or type in browser like "localhost:8080/strutsregistration" it loaded the welcome file  login.jsp mention in web.xml. Instead of calling login.jsp, it should call particular action in struts.xml. how to configure web.xml to call particular action on application startup.

Comment: You can use action mapping as "/" in struts.xml instead of welcome file in web.xml. If you map this it will invoke mapped action and from there you can return the required jsp.

Comment: Redirect from welcome page to some S2 action.

Comment: Could you explain how would you like to *call particular action on application startup*?

Comment: In web.xml welcome file as index.jsp instead of giving there i want to mention inside particular action in struts.xml. So it will load by calling that action when application started